# Как сделать зависимость массива объектов в mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

У меня есть схема объекта страны, которая выглядит так:

```
{
    name: 'Japan',
    id: 1,
    ...
    cities: [
        some data...
    ]
}
```

и схема города с ссылкой на страну (countryId)

```
{
    name: 'City Test'
    countryId: 1
    id: some data...
}
```

На выходе я хочу получить список стран в которых в поле cities буду готовые объекты привязанные к странам.
Как я могу это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

В `MongoDB` за подобные объединения коллекций отвечает `$lookUp`, `mongoose` также предоставляет удобный интерфейс для этого.

Для этого, в схеме страны для поля `cities` определите свойства `localField`, `foreignField` и `ref`.

```js
const countrySchema = new Schema({
  ...
  cities: [{ ref: 'название модели города', localField: 'id', foreignField: 'countryId' }]
});
```

Далее, при каждом `find` запросе вызывайте метод `.populate('cities')`.